# Передача параметров в исполняемый bat-файл

Tags: bat

В `bat`-файле нужно посчитать количество параметров, ему переданных.
Использовал следующую конструкцию:

```
for %%i in (%*) do set /a param+=1
```

При вызове батника следующим образом:

> search.bat "путьККаталогу" "file.txt"

`param` становится равен 2

Но при вызове:

> search.bat "путьККаталогу" "*.txt"

или:

> search.bat "путьККаталогу" "?.txt"

`param` равен 1.

Как символы `*, ?` влияют на подсчет?

Comment: А зачем вам число параметров?

Comment: батник должен производить поиск в директории(1 параметр) файлов по маске либо масках... то есть нужно определить количество масок чтобы после проходится по параметрам %* и делать поиск + нужно проверить есть ли хотя бы один параметр (каталог) , если есть, то проверить наличие хотя бы одной маски

Comment: Проверяйте наличие i-ого параметра `IF NOT "%2" == "" ...`

Comment: и до каких пор мне проверять так параметры? если через for то как долго мне повторять цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте команду `shift` для сдвига параметров

```
if "%2" == "" (
  echo передали один параметр
) else (
:loop
  if "%1" == "" goto :eof
  echo текущий параметр: %1
  shift
  goto loop
)
```